# Закрыть listening порт

Tags: java, windows, сокет, port

Мне нужно закрывать listening порт(например, 12000, который создается java методом serversocket.accept) в определённый момент(неизвестно когда он наступит). Вариант "убивать процесс, создавший порт" - не подходит, процесс должен оставаться живым. Вариант с таймером для serversocket.accept тоже не подходит - необходимо в общем случае держать до подключения, и лишь в конкретных ситуациях вырубать таковой порт. Подойдёт отключение методами java(необходимо учесть, что вырубать этот порт необходимо из отличного от создавшего такой сокет потока), либо через командную строку windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем плоха наивная реализация?

```
class ListenerThread extends Thread
{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void enable() throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1337);
        start();
    }

    public void disable() throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket.close();
        interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket.accept();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block12000" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=12000 action=block
```

Comment: а если после такого закрытия порта необходимо снять этот блок и вернуть порт в доступные?

Comment: `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Block12000"`

Comment: Я проверил несколько раз, но порт при netstat всё еще остаётся открытым и продолжает прослушивание. Как этому порту полностью прекратить своё прослушивание и отрубиться?

Comment: Порт прослушивается, но подключиться к нему нельзя. Прекратить прослушивание можно только закрыв сокет в коде, который его открыл.

Comment: А иначе, системными средствами - нельзя?